# MySQL Query returning same row twice

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I am trying to display data using 3 tables

```
posts
  - id
  - category_id
  - user_authors_id
  - title
  - status

user_authors
  - id
  - author_name

categories
  - id
  - name

subcategories
  - id
  - name
```

What I am trying to do is. I am creating a view panel that will display the posts. So, i am using 3 tables. From user_authors I'll get the author name, from categories table I'll get the category name, now the category tables have subcategory id, so I also want to get the subcategory name.

I am having two rows in the `posts` table with id `29 and 30` but when i run the below query it shows 2 entries with the same data.

```
SELECT 
   posts.id, 
   categories.name AS cat_name, 
   subcategories.name AS subcat_name, 
   posts.title, 
   user_authors.author_name, 
   posts.created, 
   posts.status
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN user_authors ON (user_authors.id = posts.user_author_id) 
INNER JOIN categories ON(posts.category_id = categories.id) 
INNER JOIN subcategories ON (categories.id = subcategories.category_id)
```

But, if I remove this statement `INNER JOIN subcategories ON (categories.id = subcategories.category_id)` and run the query, it runs perfect, all the rows are shows properly.

What's happening, I am not trying to get it. Where is the query wrong, also it's showing no error.

Comment: Exactly the same data? Not with different sub-categories?

Comment: Looks like those results are assigned to 2 different subcategories.

Comment: add a proper data sample the actual result and the expected  result

Comment: How many subcategories are there for the category? Two? The subcategory doesn't look like it's assigned to a post at least your joins imply that. Or maybe it is in fact the subcategory, that is referenced in a post? In that case join the subcategories to the posts and the categories to the subcategories: `INNER JOIN subcategories ON(posts.category_id = subcategories.id) INNER JOIN categories ON (categories.id = subcategories.category_id)`

Comment: A [mcve] please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INNER JOIN subcategories ON (categories.id = subcategories.category_id)
```

As it is, for your query to return what you expect, there must be one and only one record in subcategories matches the given `post` :

- if more than one `subcategory` matches a given `post`, the `post` line will be duplicated in the results
- if no `subcategory` matches a given `post`, the `post` will not appear in the results

Depending on your use case, you want :

- not to `JOIN subcategory`, to avoid duplicating `post`s
- `LEFT JOIN subcategory` instead of `INNER JOIN subcategory` to avoid `posts` without `subcategory` to be filtered out

If you do have multiple subcategories for a given post and you still want to display a single row in the results, you can use the `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregate funtion to concatenate the `subcategories` into one field :

```
SELECT 
   posts.id, 
   categories.name AS cat_name, 
   GROUP_CONCAT( subcategories.name, ', ') AS subcat_names, 
   posts.title, 
   user_authors.author_name, 
   posts.created, 
   posts.status
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN user_authors ON (user_authors.id = posts.user_author_id) 
INNER JOIN categories ON(posts.category_id = categories.id) 
LEFT  JOIN subcategories ON (categories.id = subcategories.category_id)
GROUP BY 
   posts.id, 
   categories.name, 
   posts.title, 
   user_authors.author_name, 
   posts.created, 
   posts.status
```

Comment: Yes exactly happened as you mentioned, the post was not having subcategory so it was not being mentioned. After using the LEFT JOIN it was visible, now the data is being displayed but the id `30` is being repeated twice how to avoid that.

Comment: Hello @AkshayShrivastav, that's because you  have two subcategories matching that post. What do you want to do in this use case ?

Comment: I want to eliminate the rows that are having same id `posts.id` is primary

Comment: well, you will need to remove the `INNER JOIN subcategory` (and field `subcategories.name` from the `SELECT` query)

Comment: but i want that query same, if i remove the subcategory, query will be of no use, any alternate to it.

Comment: OK, then how to you want to handle the use case when there are two subcategories for a given post ? concatenate them in the same field in the result maybe, so it can fit into a single line ?

Comment: Can't we use distinct or group

Comment: @AkshayShrivastav : updated my answer with a SQL query

Comment: that worked perfectly, only I modified left join for subcategories.

Comment: but now its showing multiple belongs to sub cat names

Comment: @AkshayShrivastav You have not said what the desired output is given some input & you have not given example input & output data issustrating that. Please do so.

Comment: @GMB your answer was correct, I dropped that table and now implemented in the same table with parent id like wp and it was solved.